# my react app works locally but fails to deploy on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

works locally when i npm run start but fails on heroku. the only error i get on the logs is " This app may not specify any way to start a node process". ive tried changed the scripts. and ive tried to use the create react app documentation. ive also implemented the "https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git" build pack to the project

my file structer

```
//client
   |
   +-node modules
   + public
   +-src
   +-package-lock
   +-package.json
        
//node_modules
//server
    |
    +-models
    +-server.js
    +-routes
    +-Controllers
    +-middlewares
    +-config
+-env
+-gitignore
+-nodemon.json
+-package-lock.json
+-package.json
```

My main package.json scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run start:dev",
    "start:prod": "node server/server.js",
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"nodemon --ignore 'client/*'\" \"npm run client\"",
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "seed": "node server/scripts/seedDB.js",
    "install": "cd client && npm install",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
```

my server.js

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const dbConnection = require('./config/connection');
const passport = require('./config/passport');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8090;

// Middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));

// Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // will call the deserializeUser
app.use(session({
  secret: 'my_secret', // process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: dbConnection }),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/'))
});

// Add Auth and API routes
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/authRoutes'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/apiRoutes'));

// If no routes are hit, send the React app
app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/build/index.html'));
});

// Error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500);
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on PORT: ${PORT}`);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't added a Procfile.   If not in the root directory of your node API add a file called Procfile with no extensions i.e .js. Once you have made the file add the following line :
web: npm run start.

Comment: do i just add that next to the gitignore @xi_darius i just did it and still got a 404 not found page

Comment: @xi_darius He's using https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack which is build using https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/main/bin/release . If no `Procfile` is specified `web: npm start` is assumed. `npm start` is defined in the package.json. 
@AroParada provide the build.log. It should start like this: https://i.imgur.com/gjDwXPd.png There may be errors why your `npm start` script is not recognized. Also even when the start script is recognized other error messages will propbably pop up.

Comment: @TinNguyen added build.log